# How to draw this piecewise graph using PGF/TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Given
[image]

Is there an easy way to define the condition as "rational" and "irrational" using PGF/TikZ? A minimal example would be greatly appreciated.

This is one of the rational/irrational graphs in Calculus by Michael Spivak book, page 97.
[image]

Comment: There is no way let alone easy one. Measure zero sets on finite precision machines. I'm not touching that... :)

Comment: I'm sure PSTricks has a package for that `=)`

Comment: Besides symbolically, I don't even know how one could represent an irrational number in any computer system since the precision is always fixed, not matter how many decimal digits you allow for.

Comment: There is *no* way to draw this with *any* package. Rational and irrational numbers are dense in the reals, so what you'd see are just two segments.

Comment: I really hope there is a trick to draw at least some samples of rational and irrational. Anyway, thanks everyone.

Comment: A pixel is a small square, that covers infinitely many rational and irrational points. So there's no way to distinguish them with a picture.

Comment: No matter what precision you draw this at, it is going to look like `y=0` and `y=x`.

Comment: Another shout out for impossibility. Even if you found a way to somehow take a random sample of real numbers on a closed interval, *every single point* would be irrational.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want when you say "draw at least some samples of rational and irrational". Do you have a list of points that want to plot (in which case it is similar to a bar plot) or you need the x-axis to be real numbers (which as others have pointed is "impossible").

Comment: @mythealias: See my edit. I guess the author used approximation instead of real irrational and rational numbers.

Comment: @Chan This is more a qualitative than a quantitative visualization of the concept of (ir)rational numbers.

Comment: I am also sure it is not too slow for TikZ to plot it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no way to represent graphically this function. Your drawing tool has a thickness. If you try representing the point (1/2,0) that belongs to the graph of the Dirichlet function and `2ε` is the thickness of the pencil, you'll be covering infinitely many points of the form (t,0), with t irrational that *don't* belong to the graph: there are infinitely many irrational numbers in the interval (-ε+1/2,ε+1/2), for *any* ε>0. The same if you want to draw a point of the graph with irrational x-coordinate.

Apart from this, for this kind of drawings you need numbers in floating point representation, which are all rational; but not even all rational numbers in the interval [0,1] are representable in the computer as floating point numbers.

Thus the best representation of this function you'd get would be two segments, which is useless.

Comment: What is the area under the curve from 0 to a positive `x`?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ The integral is of course x^2/2; so what?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: egreg, I thought the integral required continuity on some closed interval?

Comment: @egreg: For me, it looks like a paradox because of the infinite number of discontinuities.

Comment: @PeterGrill It depends what integral you're referring to. But that function is almost everywhere equal to g(x)=x, so their Lebesgue integrals are the same. It's not Riemann integrable, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (0,-2) -- (0,4);

\foreach \x in {-2.0, -1.9, ..., 3.01}
    \fill (\x,0) circle (1pt);
\foreach \x in {-1.95, -1.85, ..., 3.01}
    \fill (\x,\x) circle (1pt);

    \node at (4,1) {
    $f(x) = \begin{cases*}
        x, & $x$ rational \\
        0, & $x$ irrational \\
    \end{cases*}
    $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: I think that this is the nicest representation and the nicest answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{rant}
```

> I am truly shocked that any Calculus textbook would show such a graph for that function.  I am going to add that to my book that I have been working on entitled "*Obviously Wrong!* "  BTW, this is the *first* ever public announcement of this upcoming book...  It was never intended to be technical book, but this one MUST go in there.  Although, I do have one more really shocking mathematical example, but will save that for the upcoming interview.

```
\end{rant}
```

---

Since others have given their graphs, here is mine, and the rational behind it./  Given that

1. Between any two rational numbers there are an infinite number of irrationals, and
2. Between any two irrational numbers there are an infinite number of rational numbers

I would argue that a better representation of the given function is:

[image]

If you are concerned that you do not see the discontinuities, that just means that you have not zoomed in enough. :-)  Keep zooming in and you will see the discontinuities.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  mark=none,
  ymin=-4.5, ymax=4.5,
  xmin=-4.5, xmax=4.5
]
    \addplot [red,  ultra thick, domain=-4:4, latex-latex] {0};
    \addplot [blue, ultra thick, domain=-4:4, latex-latex] {x};
    \node at (axis cs:5.5,1.3) 
        {$f(x)=
            \begin{cases}
                \textcolor{blue}{x},\quad&\text{\textcolor{blue}{$x$ rational}} \\ 
                \textcolor{red}{0},\quad&\text{\textcolor{red}{$x$ irrational}}
            \end{cases}
        $};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe Spivak must have a reason to plot the graph like that. For me, it looks like he tried to draw the difference between rational and irrationals. In fact, there are far more irrationals than rationals.

Comment: Even between any two rational numbers there are an infinite number of other rationals to begin with ...

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes, that case is already covered in my statements 1 and 2 above. :-)

Comment: @Chan Probably Spivak had a reason for making an obviously wrong diagram; I can't see one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  only marks,
  clip=false,
  mark=*,
  mark options={mark size=3pt,color=brown},
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=0.2
]
\addplot[domain=-4:4]{0};
\addplot[domain=-4:4]{x};
\node at (axis cs:6.2,1.45) {$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,\quad&\text{$x$ rational.} \\ 0,\quad&\text{$x$ irrational.}\end{cases}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From this graph, it is difficult (at least for me) to determine whether (0,0) belongs to the first case. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is the highest resolution I can achieve for you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-3}{3}{0}% for irrational
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-3}{3}{x}% for rational
    \rput(1.75,-1.5){\scriptsize
                                                $f(x)=\begin{cases}
                                                        \color{blue}x,&\text{\color{blue}$x$ rational.}\\ 
                                                        \color{red}0,&\text{\color{red}$x$ irrational.}
                                                \end{cases}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\begin {irony} Oh, I already had the hope, that pstricks would be sophisticated enough to provide a proper solution. Sad. just kidding \end{irony}``

Comment: @BenediktBauer: Don't be sad. It is just the beginning of your journey with PSTricks. The summary is that PSTricks is superior to TikZ from any point of views. :-)

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ:  Hilarious :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill absolutely!

Comment: @PeterGrill: Oh my ghost!

Comment: I'm disappointed.  I was expecting an animation with the rational points appearing at rational times.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: OK. I will try to animate it with irrational numbers of frames.

Comment: Clearly, choosing to animate this graph would be an irrational decision and therefore the animated graph should consist only of the values on the x-axis.